# Graph change in variables from summary of cases

Tags: spss

```
[a]                   [b]                   [c]
Chrome            Chrome            Chrome
Chrome            Internet Explorer Chrome
Chrome            Chrome            Chrome
Firefox           Firefox           Chrome
Internet Explorer Chrome            Chrome
Safari            Safari            Chrome
```

Im new to SPSS so sorry if this is basic. Trying to product a graphical representation (line-graph) of the change in frequency for each option from a to b. And then a,b,c.

I figure, for each variable I need to calculate the % for each option and then plot that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a perfect example for [parsets](https://code.google.com/p/parsets/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to generate what I believe you want is to reshape your data from wide to long, and then produce the summary chart. Example below:

```
*Making fake data that looks like yours.
input program.
loop #i = 1 to 1000.
    compute caseid = #i.
    compute A = TRUNC(RV.UNIFORM(1,4)).
    compute B = TRUNC(RV.UNIFORM(1,4)).
    compute C = TRUNC(RV.UNIFORM(1,4)).
    end case.
end loop.
end file.
end input program.
dataset name Sim.
value labels A B C
1 'Chrome'
2 'Firefox'
3 'IE'.

*Reshape Wide to long.
VARSTOCASES
/MAKE Browser from A B C
/INDEX Period.

*Now make the summary chart.
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=Period COUNT()[name="COUNT"] Browser
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
 SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
 DATA: Period=col(source(s), name("Period"), unit.category())
 DATA: COUNT=col(source(s), name("COUNT"))
 DATA: Browser=col(source(s), name("Browser"), unit.category())
 GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("Period"))
 GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Count"))
 GUIDE: legend(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior), label("Browser"))
 SCALE: cat(dim(1))
 SCALE: linear(dim(2))
 SCALE: cat(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior), include("1.00", "2.00","3.00"))
 ELEMENT: line(position(Period*COUNT), color.interior(Browser), missing.wings())
END GPL.
```

Which produces this chart:

[image]

If you have repeated measures data (i.e. the same persons browser over multiple time periods) you have more structure in the data that can be charted. One way You may consider area charts conditioned on the initial state. Below is an example, which with some post-hoc editing the chart produces this:

[image]

```
do if Period = 1.
    compute initial_browser = Browser.
else if Period > 1.
    compute initial_browser = lag(Browser).
end if.
value labels initial_browser
1 'Chrome'
2 'Firefox'
3 'IE'.

GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=Period COUNT()[name=
  "COUNT"] initial_browser Browser
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
 SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
 DATA: Period=col(source(s), name("Period"), unit.category())
 DATA: COUNT=col(source(s), name("COUNT"))
 DATA: initial_browser=col(source(s), name("initial_browser"),unit.category())
 DATA: Browser=col(source(s), name("Browser"), unit.category())
 GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("Period"))
 GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Count"))
 GUIDE: axis(dim(4), label("Initial Browser"), opposite())
 GUIDE: legend(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior), label("Browser"))
 SCALE: cat(dim(1))
 SCALE: linear(dim(2), include(0))
 SCALE: cat(dim(4))
 SCALE: cat(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior), include("1.00", "2.00",
  "3.00"))
 ELEMENT: area.stack(position(Period*COUNT*1*initial_browser),
  color.interior(Browser), missing.wings())
END GPL.
```

There are alot of other charting possibilities if this is the case.

Comment: Thank you very much! P.S. This greatly helped my understanding of the software too!